# How to make spring cloud connect to an existing RabbitMQ Exchange and queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

So I have a spring boot appplication and I am using spring cloud to connect to my RabbitMQ server.I read the documentation but some things are still vague to me .For now my application creates the queue and destroys it on app start and stop which is not what i want. So my question is: what is the binding bame in the documentatiin and how should the configuration file look like? I'm trying to avoid the use of any annotations and only doing it through the configuration file.

I tried following some examples and thoroughly read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges

> If you have an existing exchange/queue that you wish to use, you can completely disable automatic provisioning as follows, assuming the exchange is named myExchange and the queue is named myQueue:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding name>.destination=myExchange

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding name>.group=myQueue

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.bindQueue=false

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.declareExchange=false

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
```

> If you want the binder to provision the queue/exchange, but you want to do it using something other than the defaults discussed here, use the following properties. Refer to the property documentation above for more information.

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=myRoutingKey

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.consumer.exchangeType=<type>

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<binding name>.producer.routingKeyExpression='myRoutingKey'
```

Comment: Thank you , but what does binding name refer to ? Is it the routing key?

Comment: If you have say `Consumer<Something> myConsumer`; the binding name is `myConsumer-in-0`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names or you can map it to another name - scroll down to **Descriptive Binding Names**